# Devices don’t automatically reconnect to nearest Google Nest Wifi point

Tags: google-wifi

I’ve got a home Google Wifi network comprising: 1 Nest router, 1 Nest Wifi point, and 2 Google Wifi points. These are all compatible. The Google Wifi app shows the mesh network is healthy.

But I’ve noticed that connected devices frequently show only 1 or 2 bars of Wifi, because I have moved the device upstairs but it stays connected to a WiFi point downstairs, for example. I can confirm on the Google WiFi app that the device is still connected to a faraway point. This seems to happen for all devices (various phones, laptops etc). They don’t seem to be able to notice when they are suddenly much closer to another point with much better signal.

I can fix it by turning the device’s wifi off and on again, then it usually connects to the nearest point. But isn’t a mesh network supposed to work better than this? At my company office my phone always seems to have good WiFi as I move around the building. Why can’t my home Google Wifi network work the same way?